# Copy and Paste not working in TextFormField & TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-textinputfield

### **Solved**: COPY & PASTE Not Working in TextFormField

Found out that I was using `Listener`'s **onPointerDown** Method to remove focus if the user clicks anywhere else in the App. But this was causing the error.

*But the problem is now how to remove focus if anyone clicks somewhere else.*

```
Listener(
    onPointerDown: (_) {
       FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
       if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
       currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
       currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
      }
  },)
```

I'm trying to have **Copy** & **Paste** feature in the `TextFormField` in my Flutter app. I tried many ways but still, it's not working.

---

Here is my Code

```
Widget textFormWidget(
   String label, TextEditingController controller, bool enabled) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: TextFormField(
    enabled: true,
    enableInteractiveSelection: true,
    readOnly: false,
    toolbarOptions:
        ToolbarOptions(paste: true, cut: true, selectAll: true, copy: true),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    cursorColor: Colors.white,
    cursorWidth: 3,
    controller: controller,
    style: bold.copyWith(fontSize: 18),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        focusColor: Colors.white,
        hoverColor: Colors.white,
        labelText: label,
        alignLabelWithHint: true,
        labelStyle: normal),
   ),
 );
}
```

Calling this as `textFormWidget('Name', nameController, true),`

If you need more code or information, please comment.

Comment: Just remove the toolbaroptions and that might work, as formfield by default comes with cut, copy, paste and all enabled

Comment: No, it doesn't work. @basudevnayak go to the `ToolBarOptions` internal code and you can read there it is not enabled.

Comment: Hey did you found any solution for this ??

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue and was not able to copy and paste. So I removed

```
FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
       if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
       currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
       currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
      }
```

part from   `onPointerDown` , and to remove focus if anyone clicks somewhere else I wrap my `MaterialApp` with `GestureDetector` and added  this :

```
 onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
```

code :

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: MaterialApp(
       //your code
      ),
    );
```